# React Intl `undefined()` must be called with an object expression

Tags: react-intl

React intl doesn't build on CI with following error:

> [React Intl] undefined() must be called with an object expression with values that are React Intl Message Descriptors, also defined as object expressions.

Tried this:
[Issue link](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/issues/1191)
But it doesn't help.

```
import ConnectedComponent from './ConnectedComponent';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {injectIntl, defineMessages} from 'react-intl';

const messages = defineMessages({
    LABEL: {id: "CONNECTED.COMPONENT.LABEL", defaultMessage: "Label"},
});

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const { intl } = ownProps;
    return {
        inputLabel: intl.formatMessage(messages.LABEL),
    };
};

export default injectIntl(connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(ConnectedComponent));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in babel-plugin-react-intl [1], which is supposedly fixed already.

[1] https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/37